# In Swift looking to align a watermark to the left instead of the right

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I purchased an app template that I need a bit of help with. The app contains images that, when sent to the sharing page, get a watermark overlaid. The developer opted to place this watermark at the bottom right, but I need it at the bottom left. Can you please help me move it to that position? Here is the section of code that controls the watermark:

```
    guard let watermark = UIImage(named: "watermark") else { return}
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, true, originalImage.scale)
    drawingImageView.image?.draw(at: .zero)
    let posX = originalImage.size.width - watermark.size.width
    let posY = originalImage.size.height - watermark.size.height
    watermark.draw(at: CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY))
    drawingImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
guard let watermark = UIImage(named: "watermark") else { return}
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, true, originalImage.scale)
drawingImageView.image?.draw(at: .zero)
let posX = 0
let posY = originalImage.size.height - watermark.size.height
watermark.draw(at: CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY))
drawingImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Simply change the "posX" to zero in order to have the watermark start on the left side of the screen.